# How do I fix Cors exception by correctly accessing Sanity API keys from “.env file” to React, through client.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, sanity

I've try series of instructions from Stack Overflow and other sites but i am still not getting it right.
This is my project structure [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVwri.png)

client.js file which is in my react src folder

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
  // projectId: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID,
  projectId: `${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID}`,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2021-08-31',
  useCdn: true,
  // token: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN,
  token: `${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN}`,
  ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true,

});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

.env file which is in my root directory

```
SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID = my_sanity_project_id
SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN = my_sanity_token
```

[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPcKl.png)

Cors Origin which is from my Sanity admin page
[Cors Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfnuS.png)

my console log after i start both Sanity server and React
[Cors exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJP8g.jpg)

i try accessing sanity server like this, through client.js

```js
    //Some code...
    projectId: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID,
    //Some code...
    token: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN,
    //Some code...
```

but i receive a blank page with projectId error which was like this
[projectId_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeOIv.png)

Using this method, solve the projectId error but i still couldn't receive my fetch data from sanity

```js
    //Some code...
   projectId: `${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID}`,
   //Some code...
   token: `${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN}`,
   //Some code...
```

This only helps display static React contents like this
[React static content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYMRm.png)

I also try deleting all of my Cors Origin links from the Sanity admin panel and re-adding them; I try using Firefox, Chrome, and Safari in Incognito/private and normal mode but I just couldn’t solve it. I don't know where I am getting it wrong so I will appreciate your help in solving my problem.
Thank you.

Comment: `process` doesn't exist client-side. If you have info like API keys you want to hide from the client-side, you need to route API requests through the backend.

Comment: Oh okay, so you mean I should add the client.js within my backend instead of the frontend right?

Comment: What I usually do is make DB requests from the backend and provide API routes to my frontend. Note sure how it work with sanity but I guess similar.

Comment: Oh, I see, Thanks a lot for the advice. Even though I am not so sure of how to do it but I will try to give it a trial and see if it will yield a fruitful result.

Comment: You already have a backend_sanity folder, what's in there?

Comment: I have my database schema within the backend_sanity folder and other default sanity configuration files.

Comment: you can use this link to see the content within it. https://github.com/Hetawk/sanity-react-blog/blob/master/backend_sanity.png?raw=true